# How to get a recent Kotlin version in a multi-project Gradle setup with Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle

## Setup

I setup a Gradle multi-project project, including the Kotlin DSL as described on in the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications_multi_project.html). My Gradle version is `7.4.1`, which is the recent version at the time of writing.

In this [part of the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html) we are told to use convention plugins for subproject configuration and we should not use `subprojects` or `allprojects` DSL.

That is the reason I ended up having

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl` 
}
```

in my `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, which is all working as expected.

## Problem

By using `kotlin-dsl` I'm wired to `gradle-kotlin-dsl-7.4.1.jar` (Gradle version, I mentioned earlier). This jar seems to specify all Kotlin related versions along the project; i.e. I *cannot* do this [to specify my Kotlin version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm)

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`

    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10" 
    // ...
}
```

Because two different Kotlin versions will appear

```sh
$ ./gradlew build

> Configure project :buildSrc
WARNING: Unsupported Kotlin plugin version.
The `embedded-kotlin` and `kotlin-dsl` plugins rely on features of Kotlin `1.5.31` that might work differently than in the requested version `1.6.10`.
```

That behaviour and the warning are described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin).

## Questions

- Am I able to use a more recent version of Kotlin in this setup, if so: how?
- Out of curiosity: where do I see the Kotlin version tracked, that is baked into Gradle? I could not find any notice in the last hand full of [release notes](https://gradle.org/releases/)

Comment: 1. atm there is no way to update the embedded version of the kotlin the kotlin-dsl relies on (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16345)
2. I think your best bet would be the gradle github (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19308)

Comment: Thanks @LubosMudrak! That explains a lot.

Comment: I'll copy the comment content into an answer so you can close this :)

Answer (score 1):

1. atm there is no way to update the embedded version of the Kotlin the kotlin-dsl plugin relies on (github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16345)
2. I think your best bet would be the gradle github
   (github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19308)